# Scala: How do I define an anonymous function with a variable argument list?

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

In Scala, how do I define an anonymous function which takes a variable number of arguments?

```
scala> def foo = (blah:Int*) => 3
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but identifier found.
       def foo = (blah:Int*) => 3
                          ^
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like this is not possible. In the [language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) in chapter 6.23 *Anonymous functions* the syntax does not allow an `*` after a type. In chapter 4.6 *Function Declarations and Definitions* after the type there can be an `*`.

What you can do however is this:

```
scala> def foo(ss: String*) = println(ss.length)
foo: (ss: String*)Unit

scala> val bar = foo _
bar: (String*) => Unit = <function1>

scala> bar("a", "b", "c")
3

scala> bar()
0
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Scala 2.12:
<console>:13: error: too many arguments (3) for method apply: (v1: Seq[String])Unit in trait Function1