# Scala: why does this not compile?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am quite new to Scala (and Spark, if this is somehow Spark-specific), so please forgive the super simple question.

To me, it seems like this code should compile just fine:

```
sqlContext.udf.register("json_extract_string", (rawJson: String, keyPath: String*) => {
    [String]UDFs.jsonExtract(rawJson, keyPath:_*)
})
```

Yet compiling gives the error:

```
Error:(31, 89) ')' expected but identifier found.
        sqlContext.udf.register("json_extract_string", (rawJson: String, keyPath: String*) => {
                                                                                        ^
```

**Why is this?**

The function being called looks like this:

```
object UDFs {
    def jsonExtract[T: Manifest](rawJson: String, keyPath: String*): Option[T] = {
        implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
        val json = parse(rawJson)
        keyPath.foldLeft(json)(_ \ _).extractOpt[T]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scala it is not permitted for anonymous functions to have variable length arguments, see this answer [Scala: How do I define an anonymous function with a variable argument list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194847/scala-how-do-i-define-an-anonymous-function-with-a-variable-argument-list)

There is a shorter form of what you're trying to express which should work:

```
sqlContext.udf.register("json_extract_string", UDFs.jsonExtract[String]_)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you :) This feels like a very strange restriction.

Comment: Yeah it surprised me too

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
[String]UDFs.jsonExtract(rawJson, keyPath:_*)
```

is not valid Scala.

If you need to cast, you have to explicitly call `asInstanceOf`:

```
UDFs.jsonExtract(rawJson, keyPath:_*).asInstanceOf[String]
```

But typically such casting is a code smell and a sign that you've gone down the wrong path.

Comment: I think given `jsonExtract`, OP will want to do `UDFs.jsonExtract[String](rawJson, keyPath:_*)`

Comment: This seems to give the exact same error. Here is a minimal test case that causes the compilation error. I feel I must be missing something ridiculously simple. https://gist.github.com/obeattie/d8a0eb9ed860b5023f63